# Python get random value from comma seperated list

Tags: python, random

I have the following example string:

> "jkbgr-ouuerg-uzge8-rgub, uirib-eioh-34fn-zdfe"

Now I want to choose a random key from this comma seperated list and further process it in a for loop, how can I split the list and choose a random value from it?

Kind regards

Comment: split: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split , random element: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get an array by using [`string.split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp), then use the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) package:

```
import random

tokens = "jkbgr-ouuerg-uzge8-rgub, uirib-eioh-34fn-zdfe"
token_arr = token.split(", ")

token = random.choice(token_arr)
```

The [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) function chooses a random element from a sequence / list. From the Python 3.9.2 Docs:

> `random.choice(seq)`
> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence `seq`. If `seq` is empty, raises `IndexError`.

I split using `", "` and not `","` because the second token would have a leading white-space. If, for some reason, you need to split by only `","`, you can call `string.strip()` or `string.lstrip()` on `token` and remove the leading space:

```
import random

tokens = "jkbgr-ouuerg-uzge8-rgub, uirib-eioh-34fn-zdfe"
token_arr = token.split(",")

token = random.choice(token_arr).strip()
```

Do with `token` what you wish.

Comment: Good answer, but please don't encourage "gimme the code" questions that show no effort by rewarding them with an answer.

Comment: I normally do respond to questions like this in a comment asking the poster to show tried code, but here I thought the string-stripping issue was something other people may stumble on and find helpful. Not to say it hasn't been warned in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Something  like this should work..

```
import random
text = "jkbgr-ouuerg-uzge8-rgub, uirib-eioh-34fn-zdfe"
textList = text.split(',')

randomItem = random.choice(textList)
```

Comment: Also nice, even if the same, thank you :D